# Method for removing data points that have high uncertainty

Tags: outliers, uncertainty, error-propagation

I have a set of data point $\{x_1, x_2, ... x_n\}$ each with some uncertainty $\{u(x_1), u(x_2), ... u(x_n)\}$. However, there exist a couple $u(x_i)$ that are 3 orders of magnitude higher than the rest.

**Question: Is there any valid way to ignore these data points, like some sort of outlier detection?**

I would still report the original data of course.  I am asking because I want to bin the data points and average them within those bins. When propagating the uncertainties it will cause the uncertainties associated with each bin to be very high.

Here's a visual example of the problem:
[image: x's and corresponding uncertainties]

[image: after binning]

Comment: It depends on what analysis you have in mind.  As you have demonstrated, for graphical display you don't have to remove the data -- you only have to indicate their relative uncertainties.  Many statistical procedures permit you to do something analogous by suitably *weighting* these data points rather than dropping them altogether.

Comment: @whuber could you please point me in the direction of these weighting methods?

Comment: There is so much relevant to this topic here on CV that I had to conduct a severely refined search to avoid picking up thousands of hits.  Try [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=weighted+variance+regression+-logistic+score%3A2+is%3Aanswer) for a start.

Comment: @whuber alot of those questions are about regression models which I'm not too familiar with. I'm simply trying to propagate uncertainty when averaging variables but a few variables have crazy high uncertainty which significantly raises the uncertainty of the average. I attempted an inverse-variance weighting but correlation between the variables makes it unwieldy to solve the solve the system of equations). Is there some valid criteria for excluding variables from the average ( perhaps IQR on the uncertainties). Thank you.